# JButtons are painted over by an image

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to make a main menu for the board game risk. There's a custom background image, and ideally I would like the buttons to appear over the image. However when I run my code, only the button called "New Game" appears, and the other buttons will appear if you hover the mouse over them. I have tried just about everything (there are similar problems on here) but can't seem to fix the problem. Maybe it has something to do with my code? I appreciate any help/suggestions!

```
package View;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

/**
* These classes set up the GUI of the Risk program.
* The main menu, dialog for setting player count, dialog for name/color       settings for each 
 * player, the Risk game board, and a menu used during a Risk game session are    included.

 **/
public class Menu extends JFrame {  

    private JPanel mainPanel;


    private JButton newGameButton;
    private JButton loadGameButton;
    private JButton quitButton;
    private JButton ruleButton;

    private String newGameButtonName = "newGameBtn";
    private String loadGameButtonName = "loadGameBtn";
    private String quitButtonName = "quitBtn";
    private String ruleButtonName = "rulebtn";

    //private SpringLayout mainLayout;
     private static BufferedImage img;

    /**
     * Constructs the main menu.
     **/
    public Menu() 
    {
        add( mainMenu( ) );
        //setTitle("Risk: UConn Edition");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 700));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);



        toFront();
        pack();

        setVisible(true);


    }

    /**
     * creates the buttons for the jPanel
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private JPanel mainMenu()
    {
        // Creates the panel
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        // Sets Layout
        //mainLayout = new SpringLayout();
       mainPanel.setLayout(null);

        // Creates buttons
        newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        newGameButton.setBounds(20,300,150,50);
        newGameButton.setOpaque(false);
        newGameButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        newGameButton.setForeground(Color.RED);
        newGameButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        loadGameButton = new JButton("Load Game");
        loadGameButton.setBounds(20,400,150,50);
        //loadGameButton.setOpaque(false);
        //loadGameButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        loadGameButton.setForeground(Color.RED);

        quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
        quitButton.setBounds(490,400,150,50);
        quitButton.setOpaque(false);
        quitButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        quitButton.setForeground(Color.RED);

        ruleButton = new JButton("Rules");
        ruleButton.setBounds(490,300,150,50);
        ruleButton.setOpaque(false);
        ruleButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        ruleButton.setForeground(Color.RED);

        // Sets button commands
        newGameButton.setActionCommand(newGameButtonName);
        loadGameButton.setActionCommand(loadGameButtonName);
        quitButton.setActionCommand(quitButtonName);

        // Adds buttons to mainPanel
        mainPanel.add(newGameButton);
        mainPanel.add(loadGameButton);
        mainPanel.add(quitButton);
        mainPanel.add(ruleButton);
    //  add(mainPanel);

        return mainPanel;
    }
    private Image createImage(){
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(
                    Menu.class.getResource("../resource/riskUconn.jpg"));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return img;
      }
    /**
     * paint method
     */
    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g)  {

        Image img = createImage();
        g.drawImage(img, 20,20,this);
        super.paint(g);


      }


    // Action listeners for Menu
    protected void riskViewActionListeners(ActionListener evt)
    {
        newGameButton.addActionListener(evt);
        loadGameButton.addActionListener(evt);
        quitButton.addActionListener(evt);
    }



    public static void main(String [] args){
        Menu m = new Menu();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting components doesn't always notify the parent or child components.  Instead of overriding `paint`, try overriding `paintComponent` and paint your background there, this is what `paintComponent` is really meant for, painting the background.

You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers.
Most top level containers have a series of layers, including the `JRootPane`, `contentPane` and even a `glassPane`, all of which will paint over the top of the a frame.

Instead, create a custom component, which extends from something like `JPanel` and use it as you base component.  You can override it's `paintComponent` and paint the background within it.  Then add this component to your frame, maybe even making it the content pane.

Remember, if a component is opaque, it will cover any child components

You should also avoid loading resources from within any paint method (especially continuously reloading them) as this can have a serve affect on the performance of your program.  Painting should paint as fast as it can.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889667/create-a-form-with-a-background-image-jlayeredpane/28889883#28889883)

Comment: The OP uses `JFrame`, though.

Comment: If I try to use paintComponent it gives me the error "The method paintComponent(Graphics) of type Menu must override or implement a supertype method" so if I do super.paintComponent(g) that gives me the error "The method paintComponent(Graphics) is undefined for the type JFrame" because I used a JFrame as @johnchen902 stated.

Comment: @user2938241 Then don't, check updates.  Overriding `paint` of a top level container just leads to no end of issues and trouble, it's just best avoided

Comment: @MadProgrammer Haha I know.

Comment: @user2938241 It would be my preferred method